# How to use matplotlib to plot only the last 50 values of growling lists?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am trying to use `matplotlib` function in Python to interactively plot only the last 50 values of 2 growing lists while a loop goes on. However, once the size of the lists grow to more than 50, the values of the plot lines start overlapping.

I want to clear the overlapping.

Here is the photo of the plot at iteration < 50. Nice and clean.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/FDDtD]

Here is the photo of the plot at iteration > 50. You can see that it's getting messy.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/rB1vM]

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ls1 = []
ls2 = []

while True:
    (some computation to get, in every iteration, 2 new values: ls1_new and ls2_new)

    ls1.append(ls1_new)
    ls2.append(ls2_new)

    plt.plot(ls1[-50:])
    plt.plot(ls2[-50:])

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```

Can anyone help me solve the overlapping part? Thanks ahead for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating new lines at every iteration. It would probably be nicer to update your existing lines instead. The code below will probably won't work straight away, but it should point you in the right direction. The general idea is to keep a reference to the `Line2D` object returned by `plt.plot()` and then using the member functions `Line2D.set_data(x, y)` or `Line2D.set_ydata(y)` to update the line at each iteration.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ls1 = []
ls2 = []
l1, = plt.plot([])
l2, = plt.plot([])

while True:
    (some computation to get, in every iteration, 2 new values: ls1_new and ls2_new)

    ls1.append(ls1_new)
    ls2.append(ls2_new)

    l1.set_data(range(50),ls1[-50:])
    l2.set_data(range(50),ls2[-50:])

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```